# Does continuity imply existence of one sided derivatives?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

From what I understand a derivative may not exist at a given point if the function is not continuous or the right and left side derivatives are not equal.
Does that imply that if a function is continuous, the one sided derivatives exist at it's every point?

Comment: No​​.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: and why exactly?

Comment: @user2345215 : I am impressed with your answer :)

Comment: No, you can find a counterexample where a function is continuous but extremely irregular, for example a sample path of Brownian motion.

Comment: @Marek: gave you an example now :)

Comment: Why did you accept the wrong answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an elementary example, consider

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle x\sin\frac1x & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases}$$

This is obviously continuous, but can't be differentiable on either side of $0$, because the function has points on lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: This is the kind of example I would have given.

Answer (score 2):

As user2345215 already said, it does not. [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is an example of a function that is continuous, but differentiable nowhere, and has no one-sided derivative at any point.

Comment: But note that one-sided "derivatives" can be $\infty$ or $-\infty$. I wouldn't be satisfied until I found an example where even this can't happen :)

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the function 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle x\sin (1/x) & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases}$$
It is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, but it has not sided derivatives in $x = 0$.

[EDIT: Thanks to a joke of my poor brain, in my first answer I put $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$ (that is a completely wrong counterexample!), instead of the true function I had in mind. :P ]

Comment: This answer is completely wrong! This function is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ (analytic on $\mathbb{C}$, even).

Comment: +1 to your comment!! I completely agree! Sorry, in the hurry of putting the answer online, I wrote the wrong function, that is of course $\sin(1/x)x$ as @user2345215 said! I beg your pardon :)

Comment: OK, that's better. :-)